# Rails server error - railties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After finishing the official getting started guide for RoR I played with it so much that I ruined the blog so I decided just to scrap everything and start again. 
Now that I'm trying to run the rails server I get this error

```
 /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions.rb:109:in `expand_path': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions.rb:109:in `destination_root='
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions.rb:85:in `initialize'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:17:in `initialize'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:359:in `new'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /home/nadia/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

in the gemfile I have added

```
   gem 'railties', '~>4.0.2'
```

then

```
$ bundle install
```

to try and resolve the issue. However it still hasn't work. I'm fairly new so I'm not actually sure what the error is.
Any thoughts would be appreciated. 
I'm also running rails v4.0.2 if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty weird thing to see:

> No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)

Are you trying to run this application from a directory you maybe moved, or even deleted?  That error implies that it can't determine the current directory.

Comment: Some people received this error after trying to run from an already deleted directory.

I received this error after switching databases and leaving the server running. The old server info was still showing up but I was getting this error. Restarted my rails server and everything works fine with the new db.

Basically it means that there is a significant state change on the server, and your environment needs to be reset/restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Define rails in gem file like this

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
```

And then bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. I derped. All sorted now. I was simply trying to run it from the wrong directory. 
Should have seen it earlier.